# Why does $n^{\ln {\ln n}} = ({\ln n})^{\ln n}$?

Tags: logarithms, exponential-function

**Note: this is (part of my solution to) a homework question. Please DO NOT tell me the answer!**

I am trying to compare the following functions:

> $$n^{\ln {\ln n}} \qquad\qquad ({\ln n})^{\ln n}$$

It appears that they are equal (assuming $n > 1$), but I have absolutely no idea why this would be the case.

I am missing something **really** obvious and I have been hitting my head on this for about 45 minutes. A ***hint*** would be appreciated.

Comment: Take the logarithm of both expressions.

Comment: Apply, twice, the identity $$a^b=\exp(b\ln a).$$

Answer (score 3):

Try put the two expressions into the form $e^{(\cdots)}$ and compare.

Formula : $x^y = e^{y\ln(x)}$.

Answer (score 1):

Take the logarithm of both expressions.

> $\ln(x^y)=y\cdot\ln(x)\implies\ln(\ln(n))\cdot\ln(n)=\ln(n)\cdot\ln(\ln(n))$.

Answer (score 0):

Use substitution 
\begin{align}
n&=\exp(t).
\end{align}